# Data source not found when opening .qgs file

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage

I am using QGIS 3.6.1 with the new geopackage (`.gpkg`) format. When some of my co-workers open my `.qgs`-file, QGIS (same version as mine) does to not find the data source for most of the layers. Strangely, most of the layers appear 3 times. I get the same when I try to add a layer to my geopackage database. In my database, I can see only 1 layer with the same name.

When I open the `.qgs`-file, I don't have any problems. My co-workers have read-only access to the folder where the `.qgs`-file is located. Maybe it has something to do with it?

How can I fix the data source problem?

[image: example]

Comment: Have you got any generic geometry columns in your geopackage?

Comment: You mean like length or area? I have.

Comment: Did you and the other people are using the same letter for the network folder ? if you use something like "S:\SomePath\QGISFolder" and other use "V:\SomePath\QGISFolder" this could be the issue

Comment: What operating system and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `.gpkg` files are probably on a directory that only you can access (i.e. on your local hard drive, instead of on a shared network directory).

Try moving the `.gpkg` files to a place where they can also see the files, and with the same reference.
A good idea, to avoid absolute-path issues, would be to have the source files (geopackages, shapefiles, etc) in a folder at the same level as your `.qgs` file.

```
* network_accessible_share:
   * yourfile.qgs
   * layers
      * abc_gesamt_def.gpkg
      * def_gesamt_ghi.gpkg
      * ghi_gesamt_jkl.shp
```

Comment: The .gpkg file is in the same folder as the .qgs file. Both are on a shared network directory. The only difference is that I have read and write permissions while the others don't.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifiyng, that excludes some solutions. I would suggest to edit the original question, stating that also gpkg files are network accessible from your colleagues (as opposed as only the qgs file only).

Comment: If you grant your colleagues write privileges to a single file (to test) will that file be still in the list of unavailable layers?

Comment: @geopackage80 Are you accessing the files using a mapped network drive or with the network path?